# Error: Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array in Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

This is a function to add a dictionary as a subitem of a main document.

```
addSubItem = function(id, data) {
  s = Item.findOne(id);
  if(s){
    Item.update({_id:id},{$push:{'subItemsList':data}});
  }
};
```

I verify the data passed and are a valid main document id a subitem data.

```
data = {num:1, value: 'Subitem1'};
```

This works fine yesterday with the latest version of meteor (0.4.2), but today I get this message at javascript console:

```
Error: Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array
```

I created and setup a new project and I still get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lloyd, Nice workaround and thanks for the javascript crash course (i'm a begginer on it), but I found the solution: (note the "$push")

```
addSubItem = function(id, data) {
  s = Item.findOne(id);
  if(s){
    Item.update({_id:id},{"$push":{'subItemsList':data}});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
addSubItem = function(id, data) {
  s = Item.findOne(id);
  if(s){
    s.subItemsList = s.subItemsList || [];
    s.subItemsList.push(data);
    Item.update(id, s);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but 
    s.subItemsList = data;
overwrite the subItemsList, and the previous behavior is to add a new "data" to an existing array (subItemsList).

Comment: In the line    s.subItemsList.push(data);    s.subItemsList has no push method.